# Error when plotting from a pandas dataframe using matplotlib, with different IPython versions

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, ipython

I am facing a strange problem, when trying to simply plot a dummy histogram from fake data (copy/paste from pandas documentation).
What causes this crash?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1,2,3,4],
                   'C' : pd.Series(1,index=list(range(4)),dtype='float32'),
                   'D' : np.array([3] * 4,dtype='int32'),
                   'E' : pd.Categorical(["test","train","test","train"]),
                   'F' : 'foo' })
c=['A']

plt.figure()
plt.hist(df[c])
plt.show()
```

When running with `ipython2 ttplot.py -i`, I obtain the following output:

```
Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:42:40)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 4.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/srv/logs/tiaki/sentryo/exps/tools/ttplot.py in <module>()
     28
     29 plt.figure()
---> 30 plt.hist(df[c])
     31 plt.show()
     32

/home/inendi/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.pyc in hist(x, bins, range, normed, weights, cumulative, bottom, histtype, align, orientation, rwidth, log, color, label, stacked, hold, data, **kwargs)
   2956                       histtype=histtype, align=align, orientation=orientation,
   2957                       rwidth=rwidth, log=log, color=color, label=label,
-> 2958                       stacked=stacked, data=data, **kwargs)
   2959     finally:
   2960         ax.hold(washold)

/home/inendi/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.pyc in inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1810                     warnings.warn(msg % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1811                                   RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1812             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1813         pre_doc = inner.__doc__
   1814         if pre_doc is None:

/home/inendi/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.pyc in hist(self, x, bins, range, normed, weights, cumulative, bottom, histtype, align, orientation, rwidth, log, color, label, stacked, **kwargs)
   5993             xmax = -np.inf
   5994             for xi in x:
-> 5995                 if len(xi) > 0:
   5996                     xmin = min(xmin, xi.min())
   5997                     xmax = max(xmax, xi.max())

TypeError: len() of unsized object

In [1]:
```

With `ipython3 ttplot.py -i`, I obtain the following output:

```
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct  8 2014, 10:45:20)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2133             try:
-> 2134                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2135             except KeyError:

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4164)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4028)()

pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13166)()

pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13120)()

KeyError: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/srv/logs/tiaki/sentryo/exps/tools/ttplot.py in <module>()
     28
     29 plt.figure()
---> 30 plt.hist(df[c])
     31 plt.show()
     32

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in hist(x, bins, range, normed, weights, cumulative, bottom, histtype, align, orientation, rwidth, log, color, label, stacked, hold, **kwargs)
   2894                       histtype=histtype, align=align, orientation=orientation,
   2895                       rwidth=rwidth, log=log, color=color, label=label,
-> 2896                       stacked=stacked, **kwargs)
   2897         draw_if_interactive()
   2898     finally:

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in hist(self, x, bins, range, normed, weights, cumulative, bottom, histtype, align, orientation, rwidth, log, color, label, stacked, **kwargs)
   5576         # Massage 'x' for processing.
   5577         # NOTE: Be sure any changes here is also done below to 'weights'
-> 5578         if isinstance(x, np.ndarray) or not iterable(x[0]):
   5579             # TODO: support masked arrays;
   5580             x = np.asarray(x)

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2057             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   2058         else:
-> 2059             return self._getitem_column(key)
   2060
   2061     def _getitem_column(self, key):

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _getitem_column(self, key)
   2064         # get column
   2065         if self.columns.is_unique:
-> 2066             return self._get_item_cache(key)
   2067
   2068         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _get_item_cache(self, item)
   1384         res = cache.get(item)
   1385         if res is None:
-> 1386             values = self._data.get(item)
   1387             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
   1388             cache[item] = res

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in get(self, item, fastpath)
   3539
   3540             if not isnull(item):
-> 3541                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
   3542             else:
   3543                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items))[isnull(self.items)]

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2134                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2135             except KeyError:
-> 2136                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2137
   2138         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4164)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4028)()

pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13166)()

pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13120)()

KeyError: 0

In [1]:
```

Somehow, python2 and 3 point to different versions of matplotlib and pandas

Python2: matplotlib : '1.5.1', pandas : '0.18.1'

Python3: matplotlib : '1.4.2', pandas : '0.19.1'

Comment: You should use df[c[0]]. df[c] is taking array as argument instead of string

Comment: Could you please reply in an answer so that I can accept your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use df[c[0]], because c is an array not a string.